# Spring Boot and contract first Soap WebService

Tags: spring, web-services, soap, wsdl, spring-boot

I am currently trying to develop a Soap webservice based on a wsdl I got from an external supplier. The goal is to implement this using Spring Boot. I need to provide the server implementation from the provided wsdl. However I searched all over and tried some different combinations I am stuck on how I can implement the WebService using Spring Boot.

I tried using the example given on http://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/ but this does not give me the correct result. The interfaces to implement the webservice are nog generated.

Any hints or tips on how contract first Soap webservice can be implemented using Spring Boot?

Answer (score 0):

The issue I see you want to generate java objects from WSDL.

Preferable way is to use [cxf-codegen-plugin](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html) for that.
Then just use spring-boot as describer in example given in question.

Hope this will help you.